# Store age from Date of birth when use registration

Tags: users, datetime, cron

I am having a date of birth field in my registration form.

- I want to add the age in user data when the reregistration form is
  submitted.
- How can I update the age in the field when crone is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) Module will do the job:

> Computed Field is a very powerful field module that lets you add a custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss Army knife of fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

You can also google "Drupal Computed Field Age" for more information.